# In PHP problem to insert with button and function record in database

Tags: php

This is the code, that is not working -

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="zapis" id="zapisk" value="Запис" /><br/>
</form>

<?php

function zapisk()

{$servername = "localhost";
    $username = "test";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    $sql = "INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, email)
VALUES ('John', 'Doe', 'john@example.com')";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "New record created successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }

    $conn->close();
}
//{echo "Your test function on button click is working";}

//if(array_key_exists('zapis',$_POST)){zapisk();}

?>
```

If I activate the last two rows, at the moment as comment, the function work.
Is it possible, that the function can work, without the use of the last two rows.

Comment: where is your button to insert the record?

Comment: where you call the function `zapisk()` at button to insert the record?

Comment: Now I put the button, there was problem by posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must call `zapisk` function when form submitted.

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="zapis" id="zapisk" value="Запис" /><br/>
</form>

<?php

function zapisk(){
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "test";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    $sql = "INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, email) VALUES ('John', 'Doe', 'john@example.com')";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "New record created successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }

    $conn->close();
}

// Check form submitted and post has zapis value. 
if(!empty($_POST['zapis'])){
   zapisk();
}

?>
```

Or you don't use function and write your code in if statement:

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="zapis" id="zapisk" value="Запис" /><br/>
</form>

<?php

// Check form submitted and post has zapis value. 
if(!empty($_POST['zapis'])){
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "test";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    $sql = "INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, email) VALUES ('John', 'Doe', 'john@example.com')";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "New record created successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }

    $conn->close();

}

?>
```